VertexAI set GenerationConfig
I've changed the version of VertexAI
GenerateContentResponse response = null;
            GenerativeModel model = new GenerativeModel(MODEL_NAME, vertexAI);

but now I can't set model.setGenerationConfig(GenerationConfig.newBuilder().build());
Cannot resolve method 'setGenerationConfig' in 'GenerativeModel'


You can pass the GenerationConfig to the GenerativeModel constructor:
GenerationConfig generationConfig =
              GenerationConfig.newBuilder()
                  .setMaxOutputTokens(100)
                  .setTemperature(0.4F)
                  .setTopK(32)
                  .setTopP(1)
                  .build();

GenerativeModel model = new GenerativeModel(MODEL_NAME, generationConfig, vertexAI);

See this example here as well.
